# Using SVM regression model without cross-validation and parameter optimization

Tags: regression, svm, libsvm, optimization

I am working on a regression model of quite complicated dataset. Dataset is heterogenous in the sense that it contains elements of significantly different properties.

I am using $\epsilon$ type regression with radial basis kernel (RBF) (libsvm implementation). When I arbitarily set parameter C (~$200$) and leave the rest of parameters with default values I get really good regression outcome (using testing set, which was previously unseen by the model). However when I try to optimize the parameters ($C$, and RBF $\gamma$) I get quite lousy results.
For example using grid search with k-fold cross-validation with respect to minimizing mean square error or max error or maximizing $R^2$ on learning dataset, leads to squared correlation coefficient $R^2$ against testing data about 0.5, whereas for arbitrarily chosen parameters I get $R^2$ about 0.9.

Actually this is the first time I have such phenomenon occur, and I am tempted to interpret this as a result of the data charachteristic, and state that the possible model overtraining leads to improvement of the regression results.

I really need hints on this. How to interpret such behaviour, what methodology can I use to find the optimal parameters, what optimization criterion function etc.?

Comment: what is number of data points in your data set? how many folds did you choose for the k-fold cross validation? if your data set is small, did you repeat the grid search cv to see the performance on different combination of train-test sets? in your grid search cv, did you include the parameters that give you $R^2$ = 0.9? if you did and you use $R^2$ as the score in your grid search cv, then the results should give you $R^2$ = 0.9 instead of 0.5. I would be cautious about using $R^2$ as the scoring criteria though.